# Is it possible to avoid umask 0002?

Tags: freebsd, access-control-list, umask

Is it possible to give an automatic ability to modify files(folders and all recursively) created by one user to another within one specified folder (let's say "shared") on the basis of both users belonging to the same secondary group (let's say "coworkers")?

I've tried to achieve this by using ACL but with no success. Seems that umask wipes out corresponding bits....

I'm on FreeBSD 8.1 (but seems this problem is actual for other *NIX systems).
Googling this problem (people often refer to it as "umask per directory" problem) gives
the most relevant link: http://old.nabble.com/ACLs,-umask-and-shared-directories-td27820947.html

that is not very promising...

Want to ask ServerFault community - is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the group ID on the directory.  I've only done this once myself so I'm a bit rusty on the details, but google for SGID on linux and you should find what you need.